# Number in overlapping range

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem

You are given two integers between lets say 1 and 12, `one` and `two` 
and a integer between lets say 0 and 4 which is called `range`. 
 The challange is to decide if `one` is inside or equal the range from `two` ± `range`. 
 
 **The range is restarting with 1 after 12 and vise versa.**

For example, if `one = 2`, `two = 11` and `range = 3`, the result is `true`, as `one` is the the range `[8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2]`.

The input has to be 3 seperated integers, the order doesn't matter. Input via string with seperators possible. But the Input has to consist of numbers reading as '10' and not 'A' e.g.

Test cases:

```
one=7  two=6  range=0   result=false
one=5  two=6  range=1   result=true
one=8  two=11 range=3   result=true
one=1  two=11 range=3   result=true
one=2  two=10 range=3   result=false
one=11 two=1  range=2   result=true
one=6  two=1  range=4   result=false
one=12 two=1  range=3   result=true
```

Shortest valid answer in bytes wins.

Comment: Welcome to the site! While this challenge is understandable, there are still a few issues. For example, why between 1 and 12, and 0 and 4 particularly? Also, please keep in mind that homework questions are not on-topic here, so if this is homework (or similar), I'd recommend loosening the requirements of the challenge (allowing the integers/range to be any number, etc.). Finally, what do you mean by "Restarting with 1 after 12 and vise versa."?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Hey thank you, I picked those numbers randomly, but two has to be bigger than one. How big the range is does not really matter. With restarting I mean that your range overlaps over `two` so if `one` is 2 and `two` is 11 and the `range` is 3, `one` is still inside the range because it restarts at `two` with `one`

Comment: So if `one` is 2, `two` is 11, and `range` is 3, is the task basically to check if `one` is in the list `[8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2]`? That the range cycles round if it goes out of bounds?

Comment: Exactly, sorry If my description was irritating

Comment: Not irritating, just needed some clarification. I've edited in that example into the challenge.

Comment: `one` and `two` really should be called `A` and `B` for the sake of clarity. Also, it's still unclear IMO what is given as input and what is a constant. Are \$1\$ and \$12\$ the input values, or are the input values guaranteed to be in \$[1..12]\$?

Comment: @Arnauld From what I understand the second. Inputs `one` and `two` are guaranteed to be in the range \$[1,12]\$ and input `range` is guaranteed to be in the range \$[0,4]\$.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen That's what I think too. But a really confusing part is _with 1 (one) after 12 (two)_.

Comment: Suggested test case: `one=12; two=1; range=3 → true`. My answer failed to check if `12` was in the range due to the modulo-12 I used.

Comment: So the range cycles modulo 12 in the set [1 2 ... 12]? That should be part of the challenge text, not just a comment

Comment: @LuisMendo I think that's what OP is trying to say with "_The range is restarting with 1 (`one`) after 12 (`two`) and vise versa._", but that sentence causes quite a bit of confusion instead..

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I can't read :-) I hadn't seen that sentence. But yes, it is confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
₧╝g╙╖²╞
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=9ebc67d3b7fdc6&i=0+7++6+%0A1+5++6+%0A3+8++11%0A3+1++11%0A3+2++10%0A2+11+1+%0A4+6++1+%0A3+12+1+&a=1&m=2)

It takes input as space separated `[range] [one] [two]` and outputs `0` for false, `1` for true.

In pseudo-code:

```
d = abs(one - two)
return min(d, 12 - d) <= range
```

Hm, that's probably almost a python submission.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>10</s> <s>8</s> 10 bytes

```
ŒR’+%12‘Ɠe
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opKBHDTO1VQ2NHjXMODY59f9/Q6P/xv8NAQ)

Saved 2 bytes thanks to [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder)

+2 bytes due a bug if `one = 12`

I believe this meets the criteria. Takes `one` from STDIN, `range` as left argument and `two` as right argument

Comment: `ŒR+%12Ɠe` (`ŒR` is (inclusive) range from \$-|z|\$ to \$|z|\$) saves 2 bytes. Takes `one` from STDIN, `range` as the first argument and `two` as the second argument. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opCBtVUOjY5NT//83/G/839AQAA "Jelly – Try It Online")

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder So it does! Thanks

Comment: Your solution has the same problem as my 05AB1E answer had: it fails if `one` is `12` (i.e. `one=12; two=1; range=3` should result in truthy).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I believe that is fixed, but I'm on mobile so haven't fully tested it

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 38 bytes

```javascript
(a,b,r)=>((a=a<b?b-a:a-b)>6?12-a:a)<=r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hc3NDoIwEATgu0@xxzZZhK2KxlB4li2C0TTUFPT1Kw2JIfh3m2S@zFz5wX3tL7ch6dypCa0OgtGgl7oUgjUXpjIJHzkxsswrUjHLQvtQu653tllbdxatgD0C5AiZlJCm0LLtm9WCKATKEDY/yLgAhLCdk6XZTU80mcHf31YOY0uvo0@C/onYRqW@CzWJ2UZ4Ag)

---

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 53 bytes

Silly branchless method. Expects BigInts. Returns \$0\text{n}\$ or \$1\text{n}\$.

```javascript
(a,b,r)=>0x4C5C038B885n>>((a-=b)*a+347n*r)%282n%46n&1n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZDBboMwDEDv@QrvUJqUsJIUGFoJFVRC2pU/CC1UTChMwKb9PQsFtrabql1sK@/FTvwqP2R7aMq3zlL1Me8L0WNJM9oQEdqfzt7d2xs/9n1XhSHG0hIZWUnTc9WqIQvuc7VwPGUw1R9q1dZV/ljVJ1xgeFIUwNPBVoTAeg2FrNoc3VhcC8zWYXPPGtoA08G5sm41dx7JJq1r3n/18gfOLib@JbF/SGd@Nvkdic/SVSeUCPS9Zb1VIYNsl1nyWVoZCb0d40NNAtEgVNQNjkAA20IEgc5cF6ZJEMCA4hHFM4pHNMJUQ3sL6QAdnWemKY7L04vqcEQoTGX8U6b6sQ8CEhzpIwopAcOYbl5@cJnIssqPw6wlhdntvwA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 52 bytes

```python
lambda a,b,c:a in[i%12or 12for i in range(b-c,b-~c)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc3NCsIwDMDxu08RkMEGGazxE2FPoh7Sumph60atBy@@eo2DIQ4vOfz4Jxme8dZ7SrY@pZY7fWFg1GgODM4fXaaoD6DIynQiENhfm1yXBnX5MsU5DcH5CDbfAW4BqwKWltt7s5h8M7oSj@Hx5b2YwtWc1X8m4Wrk3@PSygbN889DwPWUpzc)

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 52 bytes

```python
lambda a,b,c:any(set(range(b-c,b-~c))&{a,a-12,a+12})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc1NCsIwEIbhvacYECTBCTTjL4I3cTOJjQptLGlcFNGrx1gQaXX78M43TRfPV0/J7Q@p4tocGRgN2h37TrRlFIH9qRRGWTTqaaWc3RlZaUKea3rI1ISLj@DEBnANWEiYOq7acvLxVe86ewy3L2@zaVyMWf9nylz0PBzPbb6gcf5@CLj8yWmwnl4)

---

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 50 bytes

```python
lambda a,b,c:any({*range(b-c,b-~c)}&{a,a-12,a+12})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY3LCsIwEEX3fkVAkEQn0Ex9IfgnbiaxUaHGEuOilPrrMVVESnB7zj3cpg3nmyuj3R9iTVd9JEagwezItbybe3KnimtpQMunEf2sIyCpEGihsBex8RcXuOUbBmsGhRBsaqm@V5OvWL2FGkTwjx/fJqigzLj6wzHx4sPHB2mdGsyC4ZXBMg9w/BBf)

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>11</s> <s>8</s> 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
α6Ýûsè@
```

-3 bytes by porting [*@Arnauld*'s JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/190067/52210), so make sure to upvote him!
-1 byte thanks to *@Grimy*.

Inputs in the same order as the challenge description: `one`; `two`; `range`.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3Eazw3MP7y4@vMLh/38jLkNDLmMA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9WGZSg5JlXUFpSbKWQn5dqe3i/tUJJeT6YLkrMSweJKOlwKfmXlgAVWSko2QN1/D@30ezw3MO7iw@vcPivc2ib/f/oaCMdQ0Md41idaHMdMx0DIG0KpA2BtAVMwhDGACo1gIgAhXSMgAygSh0TkABQCigTCwA).

**Explanation:**

```python
α        # Take the absolute difference between the first two (implicit) inputs one & two
 6Ý      # Push the list [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
   û     # Palindromize it: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,3,2,1,0]
    sè   # Swap to get the earlier number again, and use it to index into the list
      @  # Then check if the (implicit) input range is larger than or equal to this value
         # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: `D12α‚ß` could be `6Ýûsè`.

...what do you mean i just rewrote 75% of your answer?

Comment: "_what do you mean i just rewrote 75% of your answer_" hehe xD Nice approach though, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## Java 10, <s>70</s> 38 bytes

```java
(o,t,r)->((o=o<t?t-o:o-t)>6?12-o:o)<=r
```

-32 bytes by porting [*@Arnauld*'s JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/190067/52210).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##dVBBboMwELznFStORhgUaJtWEJJzD00POVY9OMSNSImN7CVVVfF2ugakkkaRzMo7nhlm9yjOIjzuP7uiEtbCiyjVzwygVCjNhygkbFwLsNO6kkJBwegJNHcV@2r8jBgtfXQsCiwL2ICCHDqmOXLjhyvGdK6XuMZQpzpEf7VYx4m7@8vcdNmMlHWzq0g5Gpx1uYcThWFbNKU6vL2D8IckKC2yhMcxv@v/PCKPfMHnU@CBgHgKPF1p4iuEfOf/OETiyRQhW35/QSHVKGpnf0voZ@gJ/cqUHJb2NSzPCHWQ40jbb4vyFOkGo5qmxUox71nVDdrU6XIvoBp4mRNTQ9U1vQO1g1N20@m1QbJKwQtUVDCXw2UYVLdl4zht9ws)

**Explanation:**

```java
(o,t,r)->                  // Method with three integer parameters and boolean return-type
 ((o=o<t?t-o:o-t)          //  Replace `o` with abs(t-o)
   >6?                     //   And if it's smaller than 6:
      12-o                 //    Use 12-o
     :                     //   Else (it's larger than or equal to 6):
      o                    //    Use o itself
 )<=r                      //  And check if that is smaller than or equal to r
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 31 bytes

```python
lambda o,t,r:5-r<(o-t+6)%12<7+r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSFfp0SnyMpUt8hGI1@3RNtMU9XQyMZcu@h/kIKtQlFiXnqqhqGOobEmV1p@kUKRQmYeVNBU04qLEySWDxILsiooyswrUVBX18vKz8zTUNeLUI9O0wAbrhmrAFJXAlanycUJUfkfAA)

**[Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 33 bytes**

```python
lambda o,t,r:abs((o-t+6)%12-6)<=r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcyxDsIgEIDhuTzFLQYu0ibU2IHIS3QyUQcaRWmUa04Wnx5Ddf3z5V8@@UGpL8Gdy9O/pqsH0lmz9dNbKWrzdsCN6dsBD47LCA7Yp/tNGW12KAIxMMT0j3u0oqmNahvtwjFlkLKbKSYlu6M8BbXu8QLV5dWhaH6yfAE)

Comment: Would it be possible to brute-force a solution smaller than this? There are only 720 input combinations.

Comment: @mbomb007 I think it would be hard. The expression is 18 bytes, which is longer than things I've brute-force before which capped out at ~11 bytes. So while there's relatively few inputs, the number of expressions to check would be very large, even limiting to operations already in the answer. Maybe it's doable with some template. Do you have something in mind?

Comment: Not really. I just thought that since there are only 720 cases to account for, maybe something like a K-map could be used to simplify or find a nice solution. However, K-maps are typically for boolean expressions.

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 35 bytes

```julia
f(o,t,r)=o in@.mod(t-1+(-r:r),12)+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/P00jX6dEp0jTNl8hM89BLzc/RaNE11BbQ7fIqkhTx9BIU9vwv0NxRn65QpqGkY6hoY6xJheMb65jpmOA4JoCuYYIrgWaakM0PtA0AxR5oAIdIwQfaJiOCZI0UD1I@X8A)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 37 bytes

```javascript
r=>b=>g=a=>a-12<b-r?g(a+12):a-12<=b+r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hc5NDsIgEAXgvadgCWmwDv7UGAfPQisQDSkGqtfHlrpoGq2L2cx8eW/u6qViE26Pjrf@qpPBFFDWKC0qlIqDONc8XCxVBQh2ygusi5Aa30bv9Np5Sw0lG0bJoZ@KMVKWxCgX9WpmtozC4MSC2fV3yFkTM0fwKduPqAvPr10DO/4n8JuI8RuAxZRMxISkNw)

Comment: Write `+12` 3 times, but I cannot save more bytes...

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 24 bytes

```
Abs@Mod[#-#2,12,-6]<=#3&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE7876Zg@98xqdjBNz8lWllX2UjH0EhH1yzWxlbZWO1/QFFmXglQ2E7DzcFBWTNWTUHfQaG62lxHwUxHwaBWR6HaFMw0BDEtgLShjoIxiG2IxDYCsg1g4iAJHQUjENsMzDQBCxuB2ca1tf8B)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 11 bytes

```
aV
aC mU §W
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=YVYKYUMgbVUgp1c&input=OAoxMSAKMw)

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 42 bytes

```
t#r=(`elem`[1+(n-1)`mod`12|n<-[t-r..t+r]])
```

`two # range` returns a function which when applied to `one` returns a `Bool`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU67DsIwDJzhKyzokKguIuU5AOIDYGIsFY0gAkSboMSIhX8vLqgw3eke9l10uJmyrGvq@6UoTGmqIlOxsImSReVOhUpfdpFklPjBgGKf57Ku9NXCEk6u2ykNAZlARx1MYC0TKSqFI4lihlMcMk4YFeO8NVRLODr8KixhyoSTOG4EttjJu51K37cHEPv2yVo4a5CeDr22ZyMhWcH9QTvyGwsRhIt7/gZBHEOvCfQaJj5eBMDl/qcc8Skp//vrNw)

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 45 characters

```ruby
->o,t,r{[*1..12].rotate(t-r-1)[0..r*2].any?o}
```

Nothing fancy, just a chance to use [`Array#rotate`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-rotate).

Sample run:

```
irb(main):001:0> ->o,t,r{[*1..12].rotate(t-r-1)[0..r*2].any?o}[2, 11, 3]
=> true
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZJBTsMwEEXXySlGlapA5Fh1SksVqfQIHCDKwiQuIEIc2WOgansLFiw4HRcJTtKkFaEL2Mwfj958jzSjzN2mWpsixUdZwLIKbiRBoraxzyhlYUKVRI7iAgMVsMt4QqnybZUXm5XcV6VBDaMdjKca@jhrYrBoZd5KaGUEY4g9WQiPgIevshbFi/vmLd5KkaLI6pynaHheZ7dPXuLGrrO1XRHANQHbZ5M5gaYzgonNhDY5RrDmuRZ70tOzIc2ONCpzCi8OMGM9PD0Ls7/AYQdPfoN/DM06azhah2et50P46rx1OKSHUydU8PQBMgk7FBoJcAKaQLZzHb/kij8LFIpAty5YQo3RF54boV2nXZ2tdjcVH7sS1/nHwfgn/naaxv/0/@WhBiuIvj7fIarlI3FFkVXf)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 27 bytes

```hs
o%t=(abs(mod(o-t+6)12-6)<=)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TckxDoIwAEbhnVP8A4Q2po0Qw9SuXkAHE9KhIiixUGjLxtmthMG4vS/vpf27NSZGmwVJ9N2TwT6IZeFQ0aJkFRWSxk6SjCYzrm5pIZHf8g1nbfwunieD7sctpyVcgkOKZTT92HrUv6jntINFgFsDBENdcF6USmGFFexPbr9Hzk9KxU/TGf30kTXT9AU)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 11 bytes

```
‹⁵⁺Ｎ↔⁻⁶↔⁻ＮＮ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMntbhYw1RHISCntFjDM6@gtMSvNDcptUhDU0fBMak4P6e0JFXDNzMPKGuGIYKmHoULBdb//5soGCkYGvzXLcsBAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes the size of the range as the first input. Output uses Charcoal's default Boolean format of `-` for true, nothing for false. Explanation:

```
         ＮＮ Two inputs
       ↔⁻   Absolute difference
      ⁶     Literal 6
    ↔⁻      Absolute difference
  ⁺Ｎ        Plus range
‹⁵          Is greater than 5
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 48 bytes

```r
function(a,b,r){a%in%c(9:12,1:12,1:4)[-r:r+b+4]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jUSdJp0izOlE1M081WcPSytBIxxBCmGhG6xZZFWknaZvE1v5P0zDXMdMx0ORK0zAFMgxBDAsdQ0MdYxDLEM4C6jSAigEFdYxALKByHROwEFAWJMnF9R8A)

Pretty straightforward, I struggled for a while to find the best way to test if a was in the given range. There is likely a method I haven't seen or tried yet.

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), <s>78 bytes</s> <s>80 bytes</s> 72 bytes

```cs
(a,b,r)=>Enumerable.Range(b-r,2*r+1).Select(x=>(x+12)%12).Contains(a%12)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc3RCoIwFAbg@55iN8FZHsWtssL0Juo66gm2MUOwCVPBt1/ToEy6OAf@j59zVBOqpnSXzqhjaVok3yXrusqLzIFAiZZm@dl0T22FrHR0E@ahQYYW@coGjEZ3XWnVQp/l0AeM06Wf6FSbVpSmATFEly4WV@tPQwE7JAmSmNL0Q9uR2JT2PjMk66mxP8a9xfPeUETCp5aMtPmp8dHmLw7vmnsB)

Edit: Range was incorrect, I forgot to count the item itself, adding 2 bytes. But I bit the bullet dealing with C#'s modulus actually being *remainder*, saving 8 bytes. Technically, this code actually treats 12 as 0, but this is still valid in this context.

Answer (score 1):

## [C#](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/), 158 bytes

```
using System;public class P{public static void Main(string[]a){int w=Math.Abs(int.Parse(a[0])-int.Parse(a[1]));Console.Write((w>6?12-w:w)<=int.Parse(a[2]));}}
```

[Try Online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lraaw5)

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 7 bytes

```
-±_B,╓≥
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/1/30MZ4J51HUyc/6lz6/7@5gpmCAZcpkDTkslAwNFQw5jKEUEYKhgYgHpCrYMQFlFcw4TIECioY/wcA)

Other valid 7-byters include:

```
-±7rñ§≥
-7rñ╡§≥
```

I found a **4-byter** which solves every test case, but doesn't solve the problem in general:

```
-±Σ≥
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/1/30MZzix91Lv3/31zBTMGAyxRIGnJZKBgaKhhzGUIoIwVDAxAPyFUw4gLKK5hwGQIFFYz/AwA)

The approach of the 7-byters are basically ports of existing 7-byte solutions. The 4-byter relies on the fact that the digit sum of the absolute difference of the first two is less than the third input for all test cases. That correlates with the desired output for the test cases, but not in general.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 63 bytes

```perl
sub f{grep$_[0]==$_%12,(1..36)[11+$_[1]-$_[2]..11+$_[1]+$_[2]]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZBRb4IwFIXf@RX3oUsgIKU4dZHVaLLXvfnmSOO0ogkCaUvcou6vu5bizNQl46Hh3n73nHNbcZH3TidZv8NqnwleITaLUkoReyBx4JIw7Pa9GSG@7pO0o884DcNz7Td1erTzEewd0N/200VlwQOkdmWAxLzIuEfHLGkvYVzQVti2BFe1KCDyjT@Y0bO/RhtvLdSxQtZb176t08Q5OrXkMOVSDYevpeCg9K@ko0Hi7NabnLvPL5PpZOTtYbEut1XyV8YA8Y@KLxRfenQ7r0BiJWqOCRb0S@LVPJccR1gEgN23pX8wl4em6@HsZzeUlYqubve3wEa6Brg4BYh5ZgPGTEbGHLP8AEBP0r5@GTNLo@aNZJ1rZePXQL0riFwgk6xhnixDSMt07zDkH0zcMtEtcwmkFRroHCi@I9SH38zjldDpGw)

Ungolfed:

```perl
sub f {
  my($one, $two, $range) = @_;
  my @n = (1..36);
  return 0 + grep $one==$_%12, @n[ 11+$two-$range ..
                                   11+$two+$range ];
}
```